# JDeveloper Deploy Desktop Application JAR With Libraries

Tags: jar, jdeveloper

Using JDeveloper 12.1.3.0.0, I have created a Java Desktop Application that uses Oracle JDBC and BC4J Oracle Domains libraries (added them through Project Properties -> Libraries and Classpath).  Everything compiles and runs fine in JDeveloper but I am struggling to deploy a working JAR file.  This JAR file needs to include the libraries as it will be placed directly onto a client machine.

Current failed attempt: I have created a Deployment Profile in the Project Properties.  This profile has my MainForm.java set as the main file and I included a File Group (Type: Libraries) with both necessary libraries checked as contributors.

After deploying the JAR using this profile, I get an error message saying "A Jave Exception has occurred."  Running the jar through command prompt using "java -jar archive.jar" I get the following trace:

> Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.vendor="Sun Microsystems, Inc."
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/jbo/JboException
>          at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>          at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
>          at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
>          at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
>          at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
>          at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jbo.JboException
>          at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>          at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>          at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>          at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>          at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>          ... 6 more

What am I doing incorrectly?  Any suggestions are greatly welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some communication with an Oracle representative, this is apparently not possible with JDeveloper on its own.  The limitation is that Java cannot get into JAR files that are packaged within another JAR.  It was suggested I use [One-Jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/), which will extract and package the necessary classes from the libraries, or create a script that will set the classpath to external libraries.

Comment: [PLUS ONE] Thanks, it definitely saved my day!

Comment: @HumanBeing If it's relevant at all, my end solution was to pull the .java files out of the JDeveloper project and compile them manually through cmd prompt. Makes it extremely easy to redeploy the project when I have to modify it. Glad my failings could help.

Answer (score 0):

Im gonna describe that in case your project has been  created  within an application like this:

[image]

So I got 2 libraries (jars) and gonna link them to my project.

**Tools->manage libs -> select user dir** on the left, click **New...** button and navigate to each of jars two times. By clicking
**new** and **Add entry**.

Next you wanna rightclick on your application(not project) and hit on **Application props**-> **Classpath and library** and have to add same libs .
Now it  should compile the app w/o errors.

About *jar deployment* and *How to add 3d party library to your project*.

Rightclick on project **-> project props->deployment->click + sheet icon** on the right -> **Profile type** -> **jar file**-> optionally check **compress archive** checkbox
(obfuscation level) & name the profile and put in **Main Class**

Now **project props-> deploy** and tap on the profile and you can see a runnable jar in **..\deploy** folder of your app by FileExplorer.

To add libs to the executable jar go again to **project properties -> deployment** and double click on the profile recently created.
In dialog **File groups -> Project output-> contributors->add**  browse to pickup jars twice.
Now its all linked and has to build  full jars.

**Use IDE helper  next time**. SO has outdated answers about **Jdev**